# Why are .gitignore files included in the 'local-change-overwrite' error each time I try to switch branches in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, razor

I am working on a .NET Core Razor Pages project that is being managed by several Git branches. I am running into an annoying issue where I cannot checkout a branch without getting this type of error:

[image]

I know that this can be worked around using

1) `git checkout -- [file]` on each of the files, or

2) `git stash save --keep-index --include-untracked`, followed by `git stash drop`.

My question is: Why should I have to do this every time? I have included this [VS boilerplate .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore), and even added my `___/obj/` folder to the `.gitignore`. If all these cache and settings files are not being tracked by Git, then why am I still getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were the files already being tracked before you added the .gitignore?

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question - I think the problem was that I never merged `master` back into my individual branches after I merged them into master. Thus, they didn't have the correct `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this is happening. The correct `.gitignore` file was added after merging two other branches into `master`. Locally, I never merged master back into the said branches, thus they were lacking the `.gitignore`. After remediating this, I can switch between branches without getting the error.